# How to chart multiple data sets in Excel mac 2011

Tags: excel, charts, multiset

I have the following data sets:

```
City    Temp    Day
LA  34  1
LA  33  2
SF  22  2
LA  24  3
SD  26  3
SD  27  4
SF  21  4
SF  19  5
LA  22  6
SD  28  6
LA  41  7
SD  29  8
SF  18  8
LA  33  10
SD  21  10
```

Requested Charts:

```
X axis: Day
Y axis: Temperature
Each line chart would represent one city, each line labeled by the corresponding city.
```

Note: There are missing days. That is, the day range is 1-10 but every city has missing data for some days.

Unfortunately, the data can NOT be reformatted to:

```
day LA  SF  SD
1   34      
2   33  22  
3   24      26
4       21  27
5       19  
6   22      26
7   41      
8       18  29
9           
10  33      21
```

---

A youtube or webpage would be ideal. I've already googled for such video/page to no avail

---

response to @pnuts:
I changed the days to dates. Two issues: when I select each block to chart, a new chart is created, ending up with 3 charts. the date axis is not contiguous. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: yes, definitely. all is needed is: multiple line graphs; one for each city. the column order can be reordered. the only thing that is not possible is to break the column 'city' into separate per city column.

Comment: @pnuts, pls see response above.

Comment: @pnuts, thank you though for trying !